# Moq Static Implicit Operator Using MsTest

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, enumeration

I have a abstract class Enumeration which implements the `IComparable` interface.

```
public abstract class Enumeration : IComparable
{         
    [JsonConstructor]
    protected Enumeration(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public int Id { get; }
    
    public string Name { get; }
   
    public static implicit operator Enumeration(string name)
    {
        return GetAll<Enumeration>().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == name);
    }
    
    public static IEnumerable<TEnumeration> GetAll<TEnumeration>() where TEnumeration : Enumeration
    {
        var fields = typeof(TEnumeration).GetFields(
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

        return fields.Select(fieldInfo => fieldInfo.GetValue(null)).Cast<TEnumeration>();
    }
```

I have created `SampleStatus.cs` class which is inherits from `Enumeration.cs`  class.

```
    public class SampleStatus : Enumeration
    { 
        public static readonly SampleStatus Completed = new SampleStatus(1, nameof(Completed));    
         
        public static readonly SampleStatus Deleted = new SampleStatus(2, nameof(Deleted));    
        
        public SampleStatus(int id, string name) : base(id, name)
        {
        }              
    }
```

I have created unit test class for `SampleStatus.cs` class.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        // arrange and act             
        var result = (Enumeration)SampleStatus.GetAll<SampleStatus>().Single(x => x.Id == 1).Name; // output is returning null.

        // assert
        Assert.AreEqual("Completed", result);
    }
```

When I call `GetAll` method which is returning null. I have mocked `GetAll` and Implicit operator method in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

In provided sample `GetAll` does not return `null` (if it did - I would get `NullReferenceException`). Issue with the sample is in the cast to `Enumeration`. `SampleStatus.GetAll<SampleStatus>().Single(x => x.Id == 1).Name` results in `Completed` which you then cast to `Enumeration`. Since the implicit conversion exists and the base class does not have definition for `Completed` `(Enumeration)"Completed"` ends up being `null` (i.e. `GetAll<Enumeration>().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == name))`).

You can fix it with removing cast for example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod()
{
    // arrange and act             
    var result = SampleStatus.GetAll<SampleStatus>().Single(x => x.Id == 1).Name; // output is returning null.

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual("Completed", result);
}
```

Comment: If I remove the caste, public static implicit operator Enumeration(string name) method will not trigger. How to mock static implicit operator Enumeration(string name) method in Enumeration.cs class ?

Comment: @SrinivasR what do you mean by "mock" in this context?

Comment: I am working on the code coverage part, "SampleStatus.GetAll<SampleStatus>()" will trigger "static IEnumerable<TEnumeration> GetAll<TEnumeration>()" method. I need to write the unit test for "static implicit operator Enumeration(string name)" in enumeration class.

Comment: @SrinivasR 1) not sure how this sentences are connected 2) mocking static methods is not a very good thing to do (and definitely not easy one) 3) the test for this method will look something like `Assert.AreEqual(null, (Enumeration)"Anything")` case `Enumeration` does not have any defined "values".